# Entity relational Diagram for Facebook

Tags: database-design, erd

I am curious to know how a Entity relational Diagram would look for Facebook. I am a bit confused because there is an overlap between friends and a user, which causes duplicate data entries in the database.

A user can make a post, and can have many friends

however,

A friend can also make a post and have friends of their own

How would you design a schema for a social media application such as facebook?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `user` can creates many `post`. 
A `user` can have many `friends`. First, this relationship is a many-to-many relationship on `user`. Then we can map it as a new entity and named it `friends` with two F.K from `user`. For example it can save that user1 and user2 are friends.

A `friend` is a `user` too. So he/she (as a `user`) can creates `post`s too.

The ER in UML notation can be like below:

[image]

Note that, this ER shows that user1 is a friend to user2 (not vise versa). But from meaning of friendship, we can result that user2 is friend of user1 too.

Additionally, Friends relationship is a graph relationship between users. In ordinary projects above ER is good. But in big and real projects you can use [Graph Databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database) like [neo4j](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-modeling/).

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine something a little like;

```
    User table - user details
    Post table - owned by a user
    Friends table - a table that stores the link between people.
```